# Transfer ownership of Google Analytics accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, account-management

I have two Google Analytics accounts that were created under my Google ID while I was with a former employer.  Is there a way to transfer ownership of those accounts?

If I can't just give those accounts to someone else then is there an easy way to recreate the accounts under a different ID without losing the history?

**EDIT:** I have been through the process to add another administrator, and my administrator privileges have been removed, but the accounts still show up on my analytics page! I can't even delete them...  **Am I stuck with these accounts forever?!**

Comment: Only the new account can delete your account from this analytics site   (and click delete and not just remove the admin privileges).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**As of June 2017 transferring ownership of Google Analytics accounts is accomplished by adding a new user with administrative permissions, then deleting the previous user.**

To add a new user with administrative permissions:

1. Click *Admin* at the bottom of the left navigation menu to view the Administration page.
2. From there, select the account, then click *User Management*.
3. Below the table of current users, enter an email address and check the boxes for *Manage Users* and *Edit*. (*Collaborate* and *Read & Analyze* will be selected automatically.) Then click *Add*.

To remove a user's access to the account, edit the account permissions accordingly using the drop down menu in the user management table then save; or click *delete* to remove the user from the account entirely.

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics Account Administration User Management interface]

It is also possible to [move a Property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en#how) from one Account to another:

1. Select the Account that contains the property you wish to move.
2. Select the Property
3. Click *Property Settings*, then click *Move Property*
4. Select destination account.
5. Choose desired permissions settings.
6. Click *Move*, then *Save*.

Answer (score 9):

Click on Admin (top right), then on the account you would like to transfer.  Click on the Users tab, then New User button.  Enter an email address, select Administrator option, and click Add User.  Now the user that was just added can remove you from the account, effectively transferring everything.

There are old posts floating around that make it seem harder than it really is.  I just tried it, and it worked.

Comment: This is currently the correct answer.

Comment: And currently, in February 2016, this is still a correct answer (tried just now and it worked).

Answer (score 4):

Go to "Analytics Settings" on the left side right below the logo. Then click on "User Manager" in the middle column. Click on "Add user" on the right top site of the table. Type in the e-mail address (note that this must be a Google account). Select "Account Administrator" as "Access Type". Add the sites which should be transferred below. The click safe. The new user can now login and use Analytics (and delete your account from this websites to fully transfer it).

Comment: I couldn't find a way to delete my account from the site without losing the data. Have you found a way to preserve the data for the new owner of the site? If you can update your answer either way I'll probably accept your answer. (See my posted answer http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/893/transfer-ownership-of-google-analytics-accounts/1439#1439)

Comment: This no longer seems to be possible. Google Analytics currently only allows creation of administrators with full access to all sites, so it's not possible to transfer individual sites this way.

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You can give other users admin access to the account, and another administrator can remove you. However, **you cannot be removed while there are still reports that were created by you on the account.** Unfortunately, when the reports are deleted all the history goes with them.

Basically, there is not a way to accomplish this without losing all your site history. We just found out the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

No that doesn't work. You can't remove yourself. If you are the owner you can't be deleted. You can allow anyone else to have administrative rights, but they can never remove you and if you remove the account from yours all historical data will be gone. I've tried this.

Answer (score 0):

At first we also didn't have the delete option, but after reloading/coming back to that Admin > User Management page after half an hour, delete button was there and old owner of account could be deleted.