# Convert Google Analytics from @gmail.com to Google Apps For Your Domain

Tags: google-analytics

Recently Google enabled its Analytics service to be used on your Google Apps account. I have it under my @gmail.com account. How can I move it from @gmail.com to Google Apps (without re-registering all of my websites, users, filters, etc.)?

Let me clarify more: I have one old Google account (xxx@gmail.com) where I have Google Analytics. I have another Google account (xxx@my-own-domain.com) where I would like to seamlessly transfer my Google Analytics to. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've found the answer:

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72273

You cheat by adding another user (the one at @my-own-domain.com) to Google Analytics, giving him administrative rights and then revoking those rights from another user (the one at @gmail.com).

Or maybe there is another way?

Here's also a similar discussion:

[Transfer ownership of Google Analytics accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/893/transfer-ownership-of-google-analytics-accounts)

Comment: Yes, this is how you do it. However, **don't** remove the original Gmail user, in case something happens to the Google Apps account. They had a bug last month where migrated Google Apps accounts kept getting redirected to the sign-up page, and the only thing that saved me from being locked out of my Analytics account during that time was that I had my original Gmail account as an admin user. So, keep that Gmail account as an admin for redundancy.

Comment: Agreed, don't remove original user, no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=611756d0687d8d76&hl=en) from Google help?

Comment: Not really. It's a different case.